# select column from a table based on a variable name in q kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table with columns sym and px

```
t:([] sym:`GOOG`IBM`APPL; px:1000 2000 3000)
```

Now, if I assign sym column to variable ab

```
ab:`sym
```

Then, running below query is giving rank error

```
select ab from t / 'rank
select `ab from t / 'rank
```

I have a requirement where I need to save the column name to a variable based on a condition and then run select query on the column which is assigned to variable.

Followed 'Q for Mortals' and 'Reference card' but no help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could achieve this. If the table is not keyed then simply use `#` with that column name (note that the left hand argument must be a list):

```
enlist[ab]#t
sym
----
GOOG
IBM
APPL
```

An alternative is to use functional form, for example:

```
q)?[t;();0b;enlist[ab]!enlist ab]
sym
----
GOOG
IBM
APPL
```

You can get the form of this query from the parse tree, for example:

```
q)parse"select ab from t"
?
`t
()
0b
(,`ab)!,`ab
```

The following is a more generic function for the functional select:

```
q){?[x;();0b;{x!x}(),y]}[t;ab]
sym
----
GOOG
IBM
APPL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thomas.
What if, we want to do "select ab,px from t"?
I tried functional form but failed miserably.  ?[t;();0b;enlist[ab]`px!enlist ab`px]