# select query with where condition using variables instead of column names in q kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table with columns sym, px size

```
t:([] sym:`GOOG`IBM`APPL; px:10 20 30; size:1000 2000 3000)
```

Now, if I assign sym column to variable ab

```
ab:`sym
```

Then, running below query is not giving proper output

```
select [ab],px from t where [ab]=`IBM / returns empty table
?[t;(=;`sym;`IBM);0b; [ab]`px![ab]`px]/ type
```

Got understanding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110469/select-column-from-a-table-based-on-a-variable-name-in-q-kdb) and [here](http://www.timestored.com/b/forums/topic/kdb-select-columns-names-as-variables/) but could not create a working query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer above is close but there are some things to consider. The query you are running is basically:

```
q)parse"select sym,px from t where sym=`IBM"
?
`t
,,(=;`sym;,`IBM)
0b
`sym`px!`sym`px
```

The key thing here is that `,` usually indicates that a term needs enlisted. Additionally for the dictionary of column names you just need to join the value `ab` to `px`. With all that in mind I have modified your query above:

```
q)?[t;enlist(=;`sym;enlist`IBM);0b;(ab,`px)!ab,`px]
sym px
------
IBM 20
```

And assuming the `where` clause should also refer to `ab`:

```
q)?[t;enlist(=;ab;enlist`IBM);0b;(ab,`px)!ab,`px]
sym px
------
IBM 20
```